# Date Difference condition in pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date, select, plsql

I've a query in PL-SQL. I want to select records where date difference to current is more then a day and some other conditions...

```
select round(sysdate - u.RecordDate) as deleteme,
       round(sysdate - u.Payment_date) as payment,
       nvl(isverified, 0) as Verified

  from user_cards u

 where ((round(sysdate - u.RecordDate) > 0) || (round(sysdate - u.Payment_date) > 0))
   and nvl(isverified, 0) = 0
 order by id desc
```

**but there is a problem here** `where ((round(sysdate - u.RecordDate) > 0) || (round(sysdate - u.Payment_date) > 0))`

ANY IDEA HOW CAN I GET RECORDS WHERE DATE DIFFERENCE IS MORE THAN A DAY???

Comment: You probably wanted to write `OR` instead of `||`(string concatenation operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get records with date difference is more than a day it is enought to substract date and test for greater than 1:

```
sysdate - u.RecordDate > 1
```

For your code:

```
sysdate - u.RecordDate > 1 OR sysdate - u.Payment_date > 1
```

More info: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i48042

Comment: Not very index friendly, though?

Answer (score 0):

I really don't like this phraseology of "the difference between date X and today is more than Y days", ... do people really talk like that? Wouldn't you usually say that date X is more than Y days ago?

Anyway, in order for it to be possible to use indexes I would go for:

```
u.RecordDate < sysdate-1 OR u.Payment_date < sysdate-1
```

If this was a regular job then it could be supported by a single column function-based index that helps the following predicate:

```
Least(u.RecordDate,u.Payment_date) < sysdate-1
```